# Moving Items From X Container To Y Container | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am facing a problem and can not find a solution code for that , i have tried looping through containers checking for the ones with free space and then looping through those containers and picking two each time and appending the required amount of items (container1 items - container2 items) from container2 to container1 and then picking container2 and container3 and doing this loop until the integer reaches the total length of containers with empty space but this does not seems to work.

I need to achieve the following:

Example: 3 containers (x,y,z) each with 4 items. When 1 item is deleted from one of the containers i need to run a scan/search/lookup for finding all the empty containers and then moving the items from another container to that empty container and do this process to all the containers.

Lets say an item was deleted from y container so now the structure would be:

x - 4 items, y - 3 items & z - 4 items. now what i want to happen is that one item shifts to y container from z and the result should be : x - 4 items , y - 4 items & z - 3 items. This is just an example the number of containers can be in hundreds and the containers with missing or free space can be multiple for example x - 3 , y - 3 , z - 4 and result should be x - 4 , y - 4 , z - 2 (y to x , z to y , z to  y) this should go backwords <<<

Any help would be appreciated

Code i have written which does not works:

**Loop through all containers with empty space**

```
shiftItems(containerWithSpaceEmpty[currentContainer],containerWithSpaceEmpty[currentContainer+1]);
currentContainer+= 1;
```

**shiftItems Function**

```
var containerOneItems = containerOne.getElementsByClassName("item");
var containerTwoItems = containerTwo.getElementsByClassName("item");

var numberOfItemsToPut = containerOneItems.length - containerTwoItems.length;

if(numberOfItemsToPut !== 0 && containerOneItems.length < 4 && containerTwoItems.length >= 1){
    for(var i=0; i<numberOfItemsToPut; i++){
        containerOne.appendChild(containerTwoItems[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those containers? Are you talking about HTML DOM? In that case, why the [tag:node.js] tag?

Comment: yes my bad , tag removed.